# Cupertino date picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

I am using Cupertino date picker . I want to achieve something like below image -

[image]

But currently it's look like below image -

[image]

This is my code -

```
CupertinoTheme(
                    data: CupertinoThemeData(
                      textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
                        dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                      onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime dateTime) {},
                    ),
                  )
```

How to achieve like first image ? Is there any library to achieve similar?

Comment: Can you link the package ?

Comment: Not using any special package.

Comment: Could not find much method that it has exposed. Only wrapping with sized Box provide some look but near. You can create custom widget 3xCupertinoPicker  inside Row.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we could do that in `CupertinoDatePicker` .

But

You could use [Flutter Cupertino Date Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker) to achieve the layout you want. You could either show it as bottom-sheet or a widget

Null Safe Version : [flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker)